# Question: Change Set Tool that Displays component dependencies

Tags: deployment, change-set

Is there a way that Change sets or Ant Builder can detect dependencies missing  from the change set  component list and give a more informative error message about which components are missing from the list of components to be deployed? I just wasted almost more than 1/2 a day  looking for components that I did not create (and did not know were created)  which reference my code before deployment.  Does VSCode have this feature?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changeset provides a way to view the dependent components.There is a button called view and add dependent components on the changeset.

You can read about it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_outbound_dependencies.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)